# Trivial uniform acceleration motion question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

There is a question which to me (someone who knows very little physics) sounds a bit easy to solve, but I can't figure out what I did wrong here.

## QUESTION

> A person climbs 800 meters per hour. After each hour he climbs 25 meters less. After how many hours will he achieve 5700 meters.

### What I've done

- The number is not far away, let's calculate it:

$800 + 775 + 750 + 725 + 700 + 675 + 650 + 625 = 5700m$

The answer is `8h`

- I thought this sounds like a regular uniform acceleration motion question

Let's use $d = x_0t + \frac{at^2}{2}$

So here we go:  $5700 =800t-\frac{25t^2}{2} \Rightarrow t_1 = 8.167, t_2=55.833$

As you can see the answers differ, so I thought maybe I should use standard uints for this equation (convert m/h to m/s):
$5700 =\frac{800}{3600}t-\frac{25t^2}{2*3600^2}$

But it didn't help either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $v(t)$ the speed of the climber as a function of time. In the first hour you have $v(t)=800\ \mathrm{m/h}$, in the second hour he will get tired so it will be $v(t)=775\ \mathrm{ m/h}$ ...remember that if you wanna know the the displacement you have to integer the function above (which is just to calculate the area under it). So your first answer is right. Remember also that if you have a constant speed it means that the acceleration is zero, so your second approach is wrong. To better understand the problem I'd suggest you to draw down the function $v(t)$ which is a constant piecewise function, the displacement, which is a linear piecewise function (when you go on the right the slope decreases) and the acceleration which will be always zero, but theoretically it will diverge at the end of every hour.

Answer (score 2):

## Expectations

The discrepancy arises because the question is assuming that you travel at a constant velocity for each hour and have a sudden deceleration on the hour each hour. So the velocity vs time will be stepped opposed to being a straight line.

The answer is close because the average accelerations will tend to the same.

## Defining terms

$v$ - velocity; $s$ - displacement; $t$ - time; $\Delta v$ - change in velocity after each time interval $\Delta t$; $u$ - initial velocity.

## Plots

Below in red is the velocity time graph and blue the displacement time graph:

[image]

Consider the following three different cases of constant acceleration:

[image]

The acceleration for each is the average acceleration of the stepped velocity shown in red. But the initial velocities are all different. Green has an initial velocity of $u$; orange of $u-\frac{1}{2}\Delta v$; and purple of $u-\Delta v$.

The displacements associated with each are plotted below using the same colours:

[image]

One can see that green and purple bound the displacement and the discrepancy increases with time while the orange is is equal to the displacement for $t=N\delta t$ where $N$ is an integer. Below are the discrepancies:

[image]

So we can see if you use the constant acceleration represented by orange then you will get a good estimate of the answer.

## Equation for $t$

It is most likely easier to just solve for $t$ by repeatedly changing $v$ by $\Delta v$ and then $s$ by $v\Delta t$ to until you exceed the desired $s$ and then back track in the previous interval.

However, below I give an explicit expression for $t$ which is an over complication of the problem, but I would argue equally satisfying.

If we define $t\equiv \Delta t\left(N+\delta\right)$ where $N$ is an integer and $0\le\delta<1$ then one can show that:

$$N=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}-\frac{u}{\Delta v}\pm\frac{1}{\Delta v}\sqrt{\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\Delta v\right)^2+2\frac{s\Delta v}{\Delta t}}\right\rfloor\tag{1}$$

where $\left\lfloor\ldots\right\rfloor$ denote the floor operation (rounding down to the nearest integer). And then using the value of $N$ one can show that:

$$\delta=\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}\Delta v\Delta t N\left(N+1\right)}{\Delta t\left(u+\Delta vN\right)}-N\tag{2}$$

And so finally:

$$t=\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}\Delta v\Delta t N\left(N+1\right)}{\left(u+\Delta vN\right)}$$

### Proof

We can express $v$ as a sum of step functions $\Theta\left(x\right):=\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\1,&x\ge0\end{cases}$:

$$v\left(t\right):=u+\Delta v\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Theta\left(t-n\Delta t\right)$$

Thus, the displacement is given by:

$$s\left(t\right)=ut+\Delta v\sum_{n=1}^\infty R\left(t-n\Delta t\right)$$

where $R\left(x\right):=\begin{cases}0,&x<0\\x,&x\ge0\end{cases}$

Substituting in $t\equiv \Delta t\left(N+\delta\right)$:

$$\begin{align}s\left(t\right)&=u\Delta t\left(N+\delta\right)+\Delta v\sum_{n=1}^N\left(t-n\Delta t\right)\\&=u\Delta t\left(N+\delta\right)+t\Delta vN-\frac{1}{2}\Delta v\Delta tN\left(N+1\right)\end{align}$$

where the second line follows from $\sum_{n=1}^Nn\equiv\frac{1}{2}N\left(N+1\right)$. Rearranging gives (2) - our expression for $\delta$.

Next we know that the solutions of $N$ must be integers and and there, we also know there are either zero, one or two solutions. In the case of one solution this is because the second solution would be for negative $t$ and so for ease let us now assume there are either zero or two solutions and we can discard any negative solutions at the end. Additionally, we have two inequalities for $\delta$: $\delta<1$ and $0\le\delta$. We can use (2) to transform these into inequalities for $N$. The former will give us strict inequalities on $N$ while the latter will give non-strict inequalities on $N$ and each should bound $N$ from the opposite side.

Taking the $0\le\delta$ inequality we can solve this for $N$ to find that we in fact get two inequalities as we are working with a quadratic:

$$N\le\frac{1}{2}-\frac{u}{\Delta v}\pm\frac{1}{\Delta v}\sqrt{\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\Delta v\right)^2+2\frac{s\Delta v}{\Delta t}}$$

thus, we expect that $\delta<1$ should give two inequalities with each forming a pair with one of the above inequalities such that $N$ is bounded into two disjoint regions. In the case of zero solutions the above expression is imaginary on the RHS and so undefined in this context. Therefore, if their are solutions there must either be two integers in one region or one integer in each region. If there were two integers in the same region these integers would have to be consecutive but we know we have a parabolic like trajectory and so the integers in general should not be consecutive. Hence, we can conclude there should be one integer in each region.

Now it is easy enough to find the integer in each region as we can just take the floor of the upper bound! Doing so yields expression (1) for $N$.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the answer, just curious: can we come with an equation for this kind of question? Imagine the number were not as easy to calculate manually as it is in this question.

Comment: I have some equations for you, and later today when I have access to a computer I will add them (MathJax is not easy on mobile). However, after considering the maths I noticed my intuition that discrepancy would decrease was wrong so I have made that edit already.

Comment: Added equations and plots, the equations are a significant over complication but hopefully interesting all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming deceleration as 25m/s². Whereas in the question there is no deceleration, there is a spontaneous decrease in velocity from 800 to 775 to 750 and so on, thus your answer is differing.